# Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, get

This is the error i am getting:AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'.

#### view.py

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    user = UserSerializer(request.user)
  
    return Response(user.data, status= 200 )
```

#### Serializer.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])

    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])

    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True,
                                      max_length=32,
                                     
                                      )
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True,
                                      max_length=32,
                                       
                                      )
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True,
                                      min_length=8,
                                      write_only=True
                                      )
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload  = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token
    
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ['token', 
            'email',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
            'id']
```

I am trying to use the GET method in rest_framework django
My email fields is okay in both places

Answer (score 1):

good thing to know this:
if you are logged in in your app, `request.user` (in views.py) will return an object of your User model (`AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings, is your primary user model).
but if you are not logged in, `request.user` (in views.py) will return an object from class AnonymousUser

so you should have permission classes on your views to prevent this error.
there are some way to do that.
**notice**: *i consider that you are using Django Rest Framework*

**1.handle permission in your settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    .
    .
    .,
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
}
```

in this way, all of your view, inherit from this setting.

**2.handle in your views**

based on your code:

*1.Function Based Views*

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   # your function body
```

*2.Class Based Views*

```
class MyView(views.ApiView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your authentication system work. but if you are using [djangorestframework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org). and [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/) then try putting IsAuthenticated Permission

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(user.data, status= 200 )
```